# Is there any way I can use the “!” key instead of “F8” key in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to [Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) and I am trying to find if I can use <kbd>!</kbd> instead of <kbd>F8</kbd> to scan back through command history and return command that match the text on the command line.

I am using Surface Pro with Type cover, and it is really a pain to type <kbd>F8</kbd> or any <kbd>F*</kbd>.

I find <kbd>!</kbd> in Linux really handy and I am wondering if I can change the key-bind or remap the same functionality of <kbd>F8</kbd> to <kbd>!</kbd> instead.

Comment: You could use `#text<TAB>` to search by PowerShell history.

Answer (score 1):

Install [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine). Add something like the following to your $profile:

```
if ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    Import-Module PSReadline
    Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key '!' -Function ReverseSearchHistory
}
```

The `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler` changes the history-search key from the default value of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to <kbd>!</kbd>.

Comment: `HistorySearchBackward` is the exact function F8 is by default btw - not `ReverseSearchHistory`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.  Powershell uses the `!` as an alias for the `not` operator.

The interesting thing is that if you run the `alias` command, it lists all the built alias's, however `!` is not listed.  So I do not think it can be remapped.  It must be hardcoded, since it used very often.

Comment: I agree with Keltari - `!` is treated as conditional negation operator. You could have a look at the PSReadline module though - have a look at the `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler` cmdlet.